# how can i pass second parameter in Redicting URL?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a redirect URL on tab menu action in which second parameter is going as null

EX Action-URL: /abc/nc/home.htm?tabURL=/jsp/dab/hij/abc.jsp?listType=abc&access_group=TPO IP

in above url 2nd parameter '**&access_group=TPO IP'** is going null any suggestion how to pass 2nd parameter in redirecting URL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL-escape your URL before concatenating it as a parameter.  Otherwise, the `&` gets parsed as part of the outer URL.

Comment: sorry did not get you.. can you be more specific.??

Comment: You need to learn about URL encoding and escaping in general.

Comment: got it need to escape '&' with '%26' its escape character @SLaks

Comment: @crazyforjava: You need to URL-escape the entire value.  There are other characters that also need to be escaped.